# ajax success call in jquery's autocomplete select not going

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

This function is completely fine up until it gets to the last part ,
which is the "success" in the ajax call.

C# is returning the correct values to be parsed, but it never even reaches the alert() function.

Does anyone see any glaring errors/ ways to make this code better (and working)?

Thank you

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        timeout: 500,
        source: '@Url.Action("GetExercises")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault()
            $("#txtSearch").val(ui.item.value)
            var eName = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("detailFill")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'exerciseName': eName },
                dataType: "text json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data[0].label+ " " + data[0].value)
                    document.getElementById("primaryMuscleValue").innerHTML = data[0].label
                    document.getElementById("secondaryMuscleValue").innerHTML = data[0].value
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: change to `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Nope, not it.... but I thought "text json" was valid, is it not?

Comment: wat r u returning from c#?if json den set dataType as 'json' or if text den as 'text'

Comment: `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LabelValueAutocomplete(primary, secondary));`  which is label: "something"  , value: "something"   in valid json    , which is  a string. will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `dataType` in jQuery AJAX depending on what you are passing from the c# server side.
if its json data then set it as `json` else if its a text then set dataType as `text`

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
   $('#Dimen').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/BindInventory/Dimen?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
                response(data);

            });

        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 100

    });
```